# Android использование фона с главной страницы

Tags: android, android-style, android-themes

Я хочу использовать в приложение фон от обоев с главной страницы, нашел что раньше это делали так:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper"
```

Задаю в стиле:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:theme="android:style/Theme.Wallpaper"</item>
```

После этого выходит ошибка в приложение. Неужели нельзя сделать это через стили и нужно менять всю тему? или же теперь это не работает?

P.S. Понятное дело что это не правильно так как стиля Theme.Wallpaper у меня нет. Я прошу подсказать, как использовать картинку с рабочего стола.

Comment: А если в этот атрибут и в `android:background` установить просто прозрачный цвет `@android:color/transparent`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб то вместо фона будет виден лаунчер или предыдущее приложение, думаю автор вопроса не этого хочет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24971896/3212712) пишут, что можно вот так получить Drawable обоев:

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Через стили можно либо наследоваться от `Theme.Wallpaper`:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Wallpaper" />
```

либо настроить используемую :

```
<style name="AppTheme" >
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
</style>
```